# What is the best way to send parameters to a subdomain in PHP

Tags: php, parameter-passing, subdomain

I have a situation and I do not know how to solve it. I have a domain named domain.com and a subdomain named sub.domain.com

Now, I have some processing in PHP to do on domain.com and I want to pass some variables and receive a response from the sub.domain.com. This can be achieved through arrays encoded in JSON. So,

1. **domain.com/process.php** creates a PHP array of parameters (encoded in JSON).
2. **domain.com/process.php** calls the **sub.domain.com/index.php?key=*validationKey*&params=....** to perform a calculation
3. **sub.domain.com/index.php?key=*validation_key*&params=....** does its calculation and then returns an array encoded in JSON to **domain.com/process.php**
4. **domain.com/process.php** does something with that data.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any solution

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve instead of how you tried to solve it. Looks like your approach may be off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution here would be to execute the PHP code directly, but assuming that's not possible for some reason(sub.domain.com is on a different server, perhaps) then you can send data back and forth using [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Given that significant amounts of data to a query string can sometimes be problematic, this code uses POST.

In domain.com your code would look something like this:

```
<?php

$key = "validKey";
$data = json_encode(['data'=>[1,2,3], 'moreData'=>[4,5,6]]);
$payload = ['key'=>$key, 'params'=>$data];

echo "Setting up cURL<br>";

// I've used sub.domain.com here, but the URL could be anything
$ch = curl_init('http://sub.domain.com/processor.php');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

echo "Executing cURL<br>";
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE );
if ($responseCode != "200") {
    exit("Error: Response $responseCode");
}
echo "Received response<br>";

$response = json_decode($result);
var_dump($response);
```

The code in sub.domain.com (I've called it 'processor.php' above) would then be:

```
<?php

// Simple key validation function
function isValidKey(string $key):bool {
    // Do whatever validation you need here
    return ($key === "validKey");
}

// Simple entry validation. Return a 404 to discourage anyone just poking about
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') ||
    (empty($_POST['key']))
    ) {
    http_response_code(404);
    exit;
    }

    // Invalid key? return 401 Unauthorised
    if (!isValidKey($_POST['key'])) {
        http_response_code(401);
        exit;
    }

    // No params, or not JSON, return 400 Bad Request
    if (empty($_POST['params']) || (is_null($data=json_decode($_POST['params'])))) {
        http_response_code(400);
        exit;
    }

    // process data here. Return results

    header("Content-type: application/json");
    $result = ['status'=>'OK','answer'=>'Answer', "data"=>$data ];

    echo json_encode($result);
```

If everything works, running the domain.com code from a browser should give this result:

```
Setting up cURL
Executing cURL
Received response

/home/domain.com/html/process.php:28:
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'status' => string 'OK' (length=2)
  public 'answer' => string 'Answer' (length=6)
  public 'data' => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'data' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => int 1
          1 => int 2
          2 => int 3
      public 'moreData' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => int 4
          1 => int 5
          2 => int 6
```

<sup>Disclaimer: This is proof-of-concept code only. It's not production-ready, and has had only rudimentary testing.</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can not wait to test it. The sub.domain.com is on the same server.

Comment: ...or just `$response=unserialize(file_get_contents('http://$OHERSITE/?q=' . urlencode(serialize($params)));`

Comment: @symcbean We're not told how much data needs to be sent, only that it's JSON. Using the query string is potentially problematic once it is larger than about 2048 characters. It depends on the configuration of the server. Using POST avoids that.

Comment: I tried now the code.. At the beginning worked the best, but now, I need to refresh the page to get the answer properly,not null. Is it fine?

Comment: @TasteMyBomb The code is only intended to show how things can be done and has had minimal testing. You'll have to adapt it to meet your specific requirements. If something's not working as you expect you'll have provide more details on what you're doing and post the code you're using. That's probably best done as another question.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Thanks a lot again for the code. I had a problem with my validation key function. Thanks.